# How I can show which image has been uploaded inside input type file with php?

Tags: php

I have database structure as such for image that it stores it name and moves upload to a uploads directory via `move_uploaded_file()`. I have a page where people can edit what they have uploaded to that specific post. Commonly it is done via giving an value for input but what ever I put inside input is not being displayed. Basically I wants to show which  image is uploaded with that specific post.

Html (doesn't works )

```
   <input class="" value="<?php echo $row['post_image'] ?>" type="file" id="addPost_post_image" name="addPost_post_image">
```

`echo $row['post_image']` shows which  image name is stored. and is giving right info.

Image is placed under a folder uploads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting 
`<img src="uploads/<?php echo $row['post_image'] ?>">`
next to input field.
I assume you have an image name saved in the database row post_image. If not then get name from `basename($_FILES["addPost_post_image"]["name"]);`.

Comment: yes your assumption is right. I can do that easily but why then value is not being shown?

Comment: because the value of fille input doesn't work like that. More about that on this link: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file)

Comment: Still it seem unfair, to me. I do understand it has some other reasons. But I think it should work like that.